# Comparing second column word with other text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

i want to only display the second column ,

this is my code

```
with open('try.txt', 'rb') as file1:
    file1_data = dict(line.split(None, 2)[1] for line in file1 if line.strip())
print file1_data
```

This is the text file

```
E5 Bat One 
E5 BALL Two 
E5 CRICKET Three
E5 Bat03 Four
E5 Bat133 Five
```

Than i have to find the Bat which is in second column of textfile1 in second text file
`Secondtextfile`

```
?Bat03|Batsman
This is the goods of cricket
Usually cricketers use it
it is game
?Balt|Bowler
Both can be use by batsman and bowler
?Bat133|Swimmer
Swiming is the best exercise
```

So the Bat which is in second column of `textfile1` we goto `second text file` and find Bat03 and Bat133 and ignore value after `|` , if `Bat` in second text file before `|` found than display it

```
with open('second.txt', 'rb') as file2, open('output.txt', 'wb') as outputfile:
    output = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter='|')
    for line in file2:
        if line[:1] == '?':
            row = line.strip().split('|')
            key = row[0][1:]
            if key in file1_data:
                output.writerow(row + [file1_data])
        else:
            outputfile.write(line)
```

Required output

```
?Bat03|Batsman
        This is the goods of cricket
        This is the goods of cricket
        Usually cricketers use it
        it is game
?Bat133|Swimmer
        Swiming is the best exercise
```

Comment: Why are you using a csv writer, then writing to the file directly? And how do you expect this output if `Bat03` and `Bat133` are not in the first file?

Comment: @jadkik94 Yes , i edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate issues.  The first is the one in your title - how to get just the second column's value.

**Retrieving the second column's value**

The reason your `line.split(None, 2)[1:]` is returning both the second and third items in the lines is because it's being told to do so.  Using `[1:]` at the end means return the second item in the list and all subsequent items (because of the `:` and [list slicing](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html).  If you just want to return the second item in the list, use `line.split(None, 2)[1]`.

**Testing lines in another file**

Your second issue is how to use those values from the first file to test the values in the second file.  Your current code seems to do this for the most part, but you don't have any code in place to capture what might be called the "description" line.  Also, it's not clear why we should be using `csv.writer` to create a file that doesn't appear to be in `.csv` format.

```
with open('second.txt', 'rb') as file2, open('output.txt', 'wb') as outputfile:
    output = ""
    file2lines = file2.readlines()
    for i in range(len(file2lines)):
        line = file2lines[i]
        if line[0] == '?':
            row = line.strip().split('|')
            key = row[0][1:]
            if key in file1_data:
                output += line + "\t" + file2lines[i+1]
    outputfile.write(output)
```

Comment: But it not fullfill my required output

Comment: @Angel that's because the rest of your code may still have problems not related to the title of your question; I'll see what I can do to fix them as well.

Comment: `with open('try2.txt', 'rb').readlines() as file2lines, open('output.txt', 'wb') as outputfile:
AttributeError: __exit__`

Comment: @Angel I think I know why that's happening - I've moved `.readlines()` out of the `with` clause.

Comment: `output += line + "\n\t" + file2lines.next() + "\n"
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'`

Comment: @Angel the code isn't pretty, but it should get the job done now (I've tested it on my own machine).

Comment: i marked it as correct output , but if discription is more than one line ,it didnt show that